# iOS UICollectionView prototype cell size property ignored

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, collectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView with two prototype cells.  The prototype cells have different widths and contain different controls (image view and web view).  I'm definitely returning the correct prototype cell for a given index (all the cells display the correct content), but the prototype cell size is ignored and the collection view's item size is used instead.  It's not like I'm manually setting the size.  What's the point of allowing the prototype cell to be sized in storyboard if the property is just ignored when it's actually displayed?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The size of the cell in the storyboard editor is just to help you design the cell. Since each prototype cell can be a different size, UICollectionView doesn't know which cell's size to pick for all the cells. That's why you set the actual size you want to use for your cells separately. You can do it in the designer by selecting the collection view and setting its Cell Size Width and Height in the Size inspector, under the "Collection View Size" heading.

Or, you can override the following method and return a CGSize object that specifies the size you want to use for each cell. Using this method, you can actually have each cell be a different size:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Example:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

Your view controller needs to be a delegate of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in order for this method to be called. So don't forget to add that delegate declaration to your view controller's .h file, such as:

```
@interface MyViewController () <UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

**Swift**

```
extension MyViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using a custom drawrect to add gradient layers, uilabel, and uiimage in my uicollectionview cell and it wasn't drawing at the correct size in my uicollection view. Putting this code in my main view controller fixed the problem.

Comment: If all the cells are the same size, a more efficient way to specify the size is to set it in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. e.g. `flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50,100);`

Comment: But is there any way to programmatically access the prototype cell from the `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` method? (Dequeueing the cell using a reuse identifier doesn't work, because that ends up calling the sizing method, resulting in an infinite loop.)

Comment: To further confuse things, resizing a prototype cell in storyboard by dragging its resize handles will sometimes change the controller's `Cell Size`, while manually typing in the prototype's size will not.

Answer (score 19):

If all the cells are the same size and you can set the `itemSize` on the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Example:

```
((UICollectionViewFlowLayout *) self.collectionViewLayout).itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
```

Comment: Seems collectionViewLayout.itemSize is not available in IOS6

Comment: It is available in the default implementation of UICollectionViewLayout - which is - UICollectionViewFlowLayout (as the answer mentions). Just cast and use. (collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.itemSize

Answer (score 7):

Swift, working for latest iOS.

```
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize = cellSize
```

I don't have enough points to reply to Sam, but the key is that it's not UICollectionViewLayout but UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Answer (score 6):

I had a Similar Issue, I set a breakpoint on the sizeForItemAt and it was being called for every cell I had on my collection, however, the size set in code was never being reflected on the device.

While looking at other collections in my project I noticed the Collection View Flow Layout was slightly different in the collection with the issue.

### By Selecting the Flow Layout in the Storyboard

[image]

### And then Setting the *Cell Size* & *Estimate Size* in the Size Inspector

[image]

This helped me solve my issue.

**However the size of the cell will not be dynamic with what is in your sizeForItemAt**

Comment: In my case, the Estimate Size was set to Automatic, setting it to None is important as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can set size of `UICollectionViewCell` in `UICollectionView` properties.

In Storyboard, Select `Collection View` at the `Document Outline`, then edit your `Cell Size` in `Size Inspector`.

And you should change Cell's size type to Default, if it is Custom.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift you can call  sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate method to set the size for each cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
                // Set the size for cell no. 0
         }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
               // Set the size for cell no. 1
        }
    }
```

I hope that helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method. In Xcode 11 or later, you need to set Estimate Size to none from Storyboard.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
      let padding: CGFloat =  170
      let collectionViewSize = advertCollectionView.frame.size.width - padding
      return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your cells are the same size, you should simply set the `UICollectionView`'s Cell size properties to the same as the `UICollectionViewCell`'s size properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use its Default Delegate . . .

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize mElementSize;
    mElementSize = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH , SCREEN_HEIGHT *0.60);
    return mElementSize;
}
```