# UICollectionView using cells with different heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

So I have a collection view controller that has 3 cells because each cell will have a different layout. My image shows this:

[image]

They all have different cell identifiers so in my cellForItemAtIndexPath function I can create the specific cell like:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *cell;


    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell1";
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier     forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell2";
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell3";
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

But when I simulate it, all the cells come out the same size:

[image]

Is there a way to force the cell to be the size I have defined or is there a more appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS UICollectionView prototype cell size property ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492186/ios-uicollectionview-prototype-cell-size-property-ignored)

Comment: Why do you want to use a collection view here, if you only have 3 cells? It'd be easier to do that with regular subviews.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this :  [Custom layout for different cell sizes in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450883/custom-layout-for-different-cell-sizes-in-uicollectionview)

or use this method :

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```